# Null-pointer exception in postProcessXLS method to export datable to spreadsheet

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Good day people. I am working on a java-ee project, specifically working on exporting a datable to spreadhseet(xls). I have a method called postProcessXLS. I use this method to auto adjust the column width of the generated spreadsheet and also to add cell styles and formatting. When i run the app, the method postProcessXLS throws a null pointer exception without referencing the line.

bean

```
 public void postProcessXLS(Object document) throws IOException,     BadElementException, DocumentException {
    try {
        HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook)document;
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(0);

        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        for (int i = 0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
            HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);

            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }

        for (int colNum = 0; colNum < header.getLastCellNum(); colNum++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Could not process spreadsheet" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post you exception as logged by `LOG.error("Could not process spreadsheet" + ex);`

Comment: `Could not process spreadsheetjava.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I suggest that the document you are passing in maybe not be a `HSSFWorkbook`  - why does the method take an `Object` tather than a `HSSFWorkbook` ?

Comment: I found the method in primefaces showcase. so i just decided to modify it. I added the auto column size line so it auto sizes the columns of the generated spreadsheet. Can you please improve the method? thanks

Comment: Sure, my going rate is $100 per hour.  Please let me know how you want to pay.

Comment: Once you get exception handling right and you're capable to ask "Why is variable X null?" instead of "Why do I get a NullPointerException?" feel free to ask a new and clear cut question with a real MCVE.